# How can I use a regex in an XSD schema to restrict certain characters being repeated in a string?

Tags: xml, regex, xsd

For example, I want to validate a string containing a phone number to enforce first a '+' followed by 2 digits, then a sequence of either digits *or a single instance of either* a hyphen or a space. The string must end with a digit.

I currently have:

```
<xs:pattern value="\+\d{2}[- ]?[\d -]+[\d]"/>
```

but this does not restrict repetition of the spaces or hyphens within the string. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "... then a sequence of either digits or a single instance of either a hyphen or a space" -- take literally, that suggests that the following are all acceptable (I quote the strings when they end with a space):

```
"+01 "
+01-
+4312345678912345678900
```

Looking at your code, I guess that you were speaking informally, and what you want could better be described as a plus, two digits, and then a sequence of digits interrupted by at most one hyphen or space, which must not be final.  If that's an accurate paraphrase, you might try

```
\+\d{2}\d*[- ]?\d+
```

If you want to allow up to one hyphen *and* up to one space, it gets a lot more complicated, but it's still expressible.  Assuming you don't want an empty sequence of digits to be acceptable:

```
\+\d{2}(\d+|(\d*(-\d+| \d+)?))
```

[Not tested.]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I agree that my question was somewhat unclear. I would like to allow zero or more spaces and hyphens, but they must not be appear consecutively, nor can they be the last character. +12 456-43 4677 should be valid, for example.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Sequence of hyphen, space, or digit, with space and digit never consecutive and not final.  `\+\d{2}\d*([- ]\d+)*` may do what you want.